# Whats the git command line that counts PR made for a period of time?

Tags: git, github

I can list the number of PRs for the year made in git in the github PR web page by adding the filter as below

```
is:pr created:>2020-01-01
```

How can I do that in the command line?

Comment: Consider using the official github cli? https://cli.github.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Git command to do this because GitHub pull requests are not a feature of Git.

There is a [command-line interface for GitHub](https://cli.github.com/), it has a command `gh pr list` which is supposed to list the pull requests based on different criteria.

Currently the documentation [lists these options](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list):

```
  -a, --assignee string   Filter by assignee
  -B, --base string       Filter by base branch
  -l, --label strings     Filter by labels
  -L, --limit int         Maximum number of items to fetch (default 30)
  -s, --state string      Filter by state: {open|closed|merged|all} (default "open")
  -w, --web               Open the browser to list the pull requests
```

So it seems there is no possibility to filter the pull requests by date, either.

Answer (score 2):

Install https://cli.github.com/.

Go to the repo locally and run:

```
gh pr list --search "created:>2020-01-01"
```